# Junit exception testing with spring transactions and rollbacks

Tags: java, spring, exception, transactions, junit

So I have a interesting problem that i will need some help with. I know a bunch of questions have been asked around rollbacks in transactions using junit but I believe my problem and slightly different. To give people a better understanding of the problem let me start from the beginning.

I have implemented a *UserManagementService* with its respective *DAO* for a user management system. There is a general method called CreateUser(User obj) that is used to create a unique user. Now, there is a constraint set that email addresses are unique so if we try to invoke this method with a email address that has already been used, we throw a custom exception called *UserManagementException* with its respective error message. All this works fine however, the problem I am having is when it comes to the unit test. Oh, before i forget, let me mention the software stack i am using [*Java, spring, hibernate*]

I have my unit test class annotated with the Transactional annotations for each method that actually hits the db. These methods also have the @Rollback annotation so that all inserts, updates and deletions are rolled back at the end of each test invocation. So the problem i am facing here is I would like to test for the unique user constraint scenario. By calling the createUser(obj) a second time with a user object with the same email address I want to ensure that the UserManagementException exception is thrown. However, since it is transactional, whenever a exception is thrown, the transaction is rollback before the unit test completes and hence fails the test. Below is the test case.

```
@Test
@Rollback
@Transactional
public void testUniqueCreateConsoleUser() {
    boolean success;
    ConsoleUser newUser;
    //first one
    userManagementDao.createConsoleUser(user);
    //second one. This shd throw a UserManagementException
    try {
        //now try and insert a new user with same email
        newUser = new ConsoleUser("Queen", "Kong", "king.kong@blah.com", "kingkong","Universal Studios", "America/Los_Angeles", false, null);
        userManagementDao.createConsoleUser(newUser);
        //if this passed this is a problem. Console users should have unique email address
        success = false;
    } catch (UserManagementException e) {
        success = true;
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(success);
}
```

The weird thing is when i am running it through the debugger, the Assert.assertTrue() method is invoked correctly but the test ultimately fails.

Another thing i tried was to add a prop to the @Transactional annotation. I added the flowing **@Transactional(noRollbackFor = UserManagementException.class)** in hopes that if the exception was thrown, the rollback wouldn't be invoked then but at the end of the test. I may be approaching this the wrong way so any ideas or best practices around this sort of testing would be greatly appricieated.

Note: Below is a snippet from the stacktrace..

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:695)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$afterReturning$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your example, but you seem to be testing against your actual DAO implementation. Rather than have unit test data hitting your actual database, mock your DAO with either a mock implementation or a mocking framework. You can then manipulate the data returned programmatically and contort it into whatever validation scenarios you want.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i am using the actual DAO impl because i wanted to see it in action. I did think about using a mock object but I changed my mind to use the actual impl instead..

Comment: I decided to use the mock object approach. Even though all the answers are valid i could only accept one :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you can confirm that an extra rollback is thrown (for example - when spring does the insert, when it sees that it fails, does it already roll the transaction back?) then you should catch the rollback, or configure spring not to roll the transaction back.

That is, clearly, the rollback which spring is implementing is conflicting with the expected rollback in your unit test.  This rollback is then confusing the rollback annotation, causing an unexpected thrown exception in the "unit-test / Spring ether".

THE SIMPLE SOLUTION : Don't enable the automated rollbacks for this test.  Tests don't always have to be perfectly elegant.

Comment: Thanx for your reply but i am not sure i understand what you are saying. If you look at the code above, the first insert it done when i call userManagementDao.createConsoleUser(user);. Then the second insert that is supposed to break the unique email constraint is done in the try catch block. You also stated that you *think* that the test isn't implemented correctly. How would you have implemented this test?

Comment: It seems you just changed your answer again :). Let me digest your new answer now...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than inserting a user and then inserting another user with the same email address I suggest first *loading* an existing user from the database and then attempting to insert anther with the same email address as the one that was retrieved.  If so you simply need to do:

```
@Test(expected = UserManagementException.class)
public void insert_duplicate_user() throws Exception {

  // Read user from database
  final ConsoleUser user = dao.load(...);

  // Create new user with same email address.
  final ConsoleUser newUser = new ConsoleUser (...);
  newUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());

  // Write
  dao.createConsoleUser(newUser);

  /*
   * If you get here, there is a problem with your DAO logic
   * and a new user (with the same email was created).
   * So, we need to clean that up
   */

  // Delete new user  
  dao.deleteUser(newUser);
}
```

This test will fail unless a `UserManagementException` is thrown.